# How to specify the order of custom task execution between projects?

Tags: sbt

### Problem

I want to use sbt to execute custom shell scripts (as a part of a bigger build) within multiple directories in an order that respects a defined dependency graph. For example, given directories A, B, C and D and dependencies B after A, C after B, D after B the following is correct:
A, B, C, D
A, B, D, C
and the following is not correct:
B, A, C, D
A, C, B, D etc.

I created a custom key and custom task.

```
val script = taskKey[String]("script")
script := println("script")
```

and defined 4 projects:

```
lazy val a = Project(id = "a", base = file("A"))
lazy val b = Project(id = "b", base = file("B")).dependsOn(a)
lazy val c = Project(id = "c", base = file("C")).dependsOn(b) 
lazy val d = Project(id = "d", base = file("D")).dependsOn(b)
```

I'm trying to run "script" task in SBT Console and it produces a random execution order that does not respect dependencies above.

### Question

Does dependsOn mean a generic dependency or some Java/Scope/Whatever specific dependency?
Is there a solution at all and if yes then what is it?